# Silverlight memory allocation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Can some one please confirm how much memory at max is allocated to silverlight client application.

For example if we want load entity of size 200 mb in silverlight client memory is it possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there are no artificial memory usage caps in Silverlight.